# NullPointerException when trying to open ZXingScannerView

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, qr-code

I'm new to Android development so please bear with me.
I have the code inside an activity that implements qr scanning. Basically there is an activity before this segments of codes, but its just clicking of a button to go here. and whenever I do that, my app crashes and **that** is the error that returns. The idea of the app is once the user click the button, it will first display a qr scanner, once it has been scanned, it will now call this **XML** File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_scan"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/scanbg"
tools:context=".ScanActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question Here"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/questionhere"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/questionhere"
        android:hint="Answer"
        android:id="@+id/answerhere"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Correct or not indicator"
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_below="@id/answerhere"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>
    <!--this textview will be programmed to be changed as correct or not-->
    <!--if answer == correct then "correct!" else "wrong answer"-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Point(s):"
        android:id="@+id/userpoints"
        android:layout_below="@id/indicator"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/userpoints"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Go"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:background="#B0DAD5"
        android:id="@+id/gosagot"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and Here is the java file

```
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

Button validateanswer;
ProgressDialog progress;
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(mScannerView);
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();

    validateanswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gosagot);                  //Im having error here
    validateanswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            progress.setMessage("Connecting...");
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.show();

            EditText theanswer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answerhere);
            String sagotdito = theanswer.getText().toString();
            RequestFactory.confirmanswer(ScanActivity.this, sagotdito, new RequestCallback<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Boolean response) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            finish();
                            //load new question
                            progress.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailed(String message) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this, "Wrong Answer. Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progress.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

continuation...

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}


@Override
public void handleResult(final Result result) {
    Log.w("handleResult",result.getText());
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final EditText answertoQuestion = new EditText(this);
    answertoQuestion.setHint("answer");
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setMessage(result.getText());
    builder.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
            TextView j = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionhere);
            EditText k = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answerhere);
            String n = k.getText().toString();
            j.setText(result.getText());

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

please help me.

Comment: you button id is 'userpoints` and you are using `R.id.gosagot`  how will that work?

Comment: you are attaching a new layout to your activity with this `setContentView(mScannerView);` so old layout is no longer attached to your activity

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 nope. it's id is gosagot. the userpoints is used for layout_below

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh so do I delete it? or change it to the layout file?

Comment: Generally, never do `setContentView` more than once unless you know exactly why you are doing it. (And in those cases, you'd want Fragments instead)

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I had the setContentView(mScannerView) in comment, I was able to run but the scanner cant be accessed :(

Comment: you might want to look for some alternate options like using `Fragment` or something because you can only attach a single `layout/view` with your activity at a time

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh okay I understand. thanks

Comment: take a look at @cricket_007 's answer to solve issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [check the examples of ZXing](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/blob/master/zxing-sample/src/main/java/me/dm7/barcodescanner/zxing/sample/SimpleScannerActivity.java)...

In your activity XML, you can add a region for the QR scanner.

> ```
> <FrameLayout
>     android:id="@+id/content_frame"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
> ```

Grab that and add the scanner view there.

> ```
> public class ScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
>     private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
>         super.onCreate(state);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_scanner);
>
>         ViewGroup contentFrame = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
>         mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
>         contentFrame.addView(mScannerView);
>     }
> ```

Your error is that you can't `findViewById` on your button when you replaced the content view with some other view that doesn't have the ID you want to find.

And even if you "switched" `findViewById` and `setContentView` around, your code wouldn't crash, but you would no longer have a button in the content view, so having the click action would be pointless.

Comment: I got it worked. thanks! but I have some issues. the Go button can be seen through the scanner, maybe you have some advice how I can hide it temporarily?

Comment: Perhaps `button.setVisibility(View.GONE)`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, sorry. Feel free to create a new post to explain your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the button is a part of activity_scan and you set `setContentView(mScannerView)` to other layout.You are bound to get this error as the activity does not have a refernce to the view(button) you are refering.

What you can do is make the mScannerView a part of your main layout and then get it with `findViewById();`